# "set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted" when i pass data from different activity - KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin

This is the part of the code that cause the problem:

```html
val intent2 = Intent()

setResult(1, intent2) 

finish()
```

When the programm is supposed to send data from the second activity to the first one, it crashes with the following error:

```html
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

E/BLASTBufferQueue: BLASTBufferItemConsumer::onDisconnect()
```

I'm trying to send a string from SecondActivity to the MainActivity